# Limit query results based on value of multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 5.6 and I have a table structure like below

```
| user_id   | email_1      | email_2       | email_3        |
| 1         | abc@test.com |               |                |
| 2         | xyz@test.com |               |  joe@test.com  |
| 3         |              | test@test.com |  bob@joh.com   |
| 4         |              |               |  x@y.com       |
```

I want to fetch the first n email addresses from this table.
For example, if I want to fetch the first 5 then only the first 3 rows should return.

Answer (score 0):

This makes certain assumptions about the uniqueness of data, that might not be true...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* FROM my_table x
JOIN
(SELECT user_id, 1 email_id,email_1 email FROM my_table WHERE email_1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, 2 email_id,email_2 email FROM my_table WHERE email_2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, 3 email_id,email_3 email FROM my_table WHERE email_3 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY user_id, email_id LIMIT 5
) y
ON y.user_id = x.user_id
AND CASE WHEN y.email_id = 1 THEN y.email = x.email_1
        WHEN y.email_id = 2 THEN y.email = x.email_2
        WHEN y.email_id = 3 THEN y.email = x.email_3
        END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return as many rows as necessary to get five emails. So you need a running total of the email count.

```
select user_id, email_1, email_2, email_3
from
(
  select
    user_id, email_1, email_2, email_3,
    coalesce(
      sum((email_1 is not null) + (email_2 is not null) + (email_3 is not null))
        over (order by user_id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
      , 0) as cnt_prev
  from mytable
) counted
where cnt_prev < 5 -- take the row if the previous row has not reached the count of 5
order by user_id;
```

You need a current MySQL version for `SUM OVER` to work.

The counting of the emails uses a MySQL feature: true equals 1 and false equals 0 in MySQL. Thus `(email_1 is not null) + (email_2 is not null) + (email_3 is not null)` counts the emails in the row.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac415e71733699547196ae01cb1caf13

Comment: I am using MySql 5.x, this solution doesn't work

Comment: Then either upgrade to MySQL 8 or muddle through with a count variable somehow or write a stored procedure. (I guess these are the options you have in MySQL, I am not 100% sure, though).